# how to return simple function in django html file?

Tags: python, html, django

I need return calculate_c value in html

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.my_view, name='my_view'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def abc():
    a = 1
    b = 3
    calculate_c = a + b
    return calculate_c

def my_view(request):
    context = {'calculated_value': 0}
    context['calculated_value'] = abc()
    return HttpResponse(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context)
```

post_list.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{calculated_value}}</h2>
<h2>Test</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/v1/newproject/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 242, in get_response
    response = self.apply_response_fixes(request, response)
  File "/home/v1/newproject/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 305, in apply_response_fixes
    response = func(request, response)
  File "/home/v1/newproject/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/utils.py", line 17, in conditional_content_removal
    if 100 <= response.status_code < 200 or response.status_code in (204, 304):
TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= dict()

Comment: You have a function, and?

Comment: I need return calculate_c value in html file and do not understand what I need write in html file - {% for ... %} or {{ something }} like this....

Comment: Please click edit and add the info to the question instead of putting in a comment.

Comment: @gb1982 I updated my answer. Note the return line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the value returned by `adc()` in your template, you could pass it via `context`:

```
def my_view(request):

    ...
    context = {...}
    context['calculated_value'] = abc()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context)
```

And then in your template you can use:

```
{{ calculated_value }}
```

Comment: instead of context = {...} I added context = {'calculated_value': 0} and get error - TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= dict()

Comment: @gb1982 Have you deleted the next line?

Comment: @gb1982 I don't think the error is there, please, update your question with your full (or most important) view, and the full traceback you are getting now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def abc():
  return (lambda a, b: a+b)

calculate_c = abc()
calculate_c(1,3)
4
```